# MySql table size increase

Tags: mysql, bugzilla

We have old Bugzilla installed 2.20 install Debian Sarge 32bit with MySQL 4.0 Server running fine. Unfortunately from Yesterday noon, It started through error stating below.

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: The table '**attachments' is full** [for Statement "INSERT INTO attachments
      (thedata, bug_id, creation_ts, filename, description,
       mimetype, ispatch, isprivate, submitter_id) 
      VALUES (?, 8983, '2014-05-07 11:21:05', 'RE  #8983-Tool-form - Bug #9270 (1).msg',
              'Email flows for questions/clarificatios', 'application/octet-stream', 0,
              0, 165)"] at /var/www/1503/attachment.cgi line 943
    main::insert() called at /var/www/1503/attachment.cgi line 94
```

By the above error I understood that, The attachments table is full & checked it with command `show table status like 'attachments' \G`

I want know to how do I fix this issue or increase the size of table. Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: Maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730579/error-1114-hy000-the-table-is-full

Comment: If your Bugzilla is Internet-facing, you really, really, really need to upgrade it. 2.20 is ages old and has many discovered security issues. Even if it's not Internet-facing, you should still upgrade; modern Bugzillas are so much better than 2.20.

Comment: We also have another server which is an upgraded server, But this one is old one and need for reference only, So you have anything that can solve this issue please.

Answer (score 1):

This is not inherently a MySQL issue as you can [see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/full-table.html) in the MySQL documentation for the error message.

You will need to determine what the problem is

- Check your kernel version ([uname -r](http://linux.die.net/man/1/uname))
- Check your disk space ([df](http://linux.die.net/man/1/df))
- Check other things in the article I link to.

Once you know the cause you can take appropriate action.

You really should upgrade too.